# Root Cron job doesn't perform chmod

Tags: 16.04, bash, cron, rsync

I have a `root cron` job which creates a directory in a mounted different HDD and then using `rsync` I am copying all files from SOURCE to TARGET. Script looks like this:

```
 date_cmd='date +%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S'
 TS_SUFFIX=`eval ${date_cmd}`
 SOURCE_DIR=/
 TARGET_DIR=/mnt/backup_hdd/system_backup_${TS_SUFFIX}

 LOG_DIR=/shared_utils/logs/backupper
 LOG_FILE=${LOG_DIR}/backupper_${TS_SUFFIX}.log

 mkdir -p ${TARGET_DIR}
 chmod 770 ${TARGET_DIR}
 rsync -a --append-verify --info=progress2 --exclude-from=${EXCLUDE_LIST} ${SOURCE_DIR} ${TARGET_DIR}
```

The problem is that `chmod 770` doesn't change the `TARGET` dir permisisons to 770. As you see it is created with 755 permissions.:

```
drwxr-xr-x  19 root root       4096 Mar 18 11:47 system_backup_2018_03_18_17_57_01/
```

My `root cron` job:

```
57 17 * * * umask 007; /path/to/script.sh
```

As you see I set umask 007 before executing the script. So, it fails on 2 fronts:

1. Although I am setting the umask to `007`, the actual permissions are not as expected.
2. Although I am explicitly changing permissions(`chmod 770`) to the `TARGET` dir, permissions are still not changed.

Any ideas why these 2 cases don't work?

**UPDATE**

Running the script with `sudo script.sh` doesn't change the permissions of `TARGET`, either.

Comment: Does it work without `cron`? I suspect the `rsync -a` to set the permissions similar to the source directory.

Comment: @PerlDuck Nope. I will update question :)

Comment: @PerlDuck Seems you are right. When commented the `rsync` command, the permissions were set correctly. Seems `rsync` overwrites them..

Comment: Show output of `stat --printf "%a" /`.

Comment: Swap `chmod` and `rsync`.

Comment: @Cyrus It is `755`. Rsync creates the target dir with the same permission of source.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to `PerlDuck` and `Cyrus` the mystery is solved.

`rsync -a` creates the TARGET dir with the same permissions as the SOURCE(in my case 755).